# Recover dropped Hive table data

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

The Hive table's data is on S3. I mistakenly dropped the wrong table. I can't see the partitions on S3. Is there a way to recover it?

Thank you.

Comment: Dropping an external table does not remove the data itself. The data is probably still somewhere on S3.

Answer (score 2):

Only if versioning is enabled on the bucket containing deleted table location, then it is possible. Login to the [S3 management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/), find your bucket, show all versions and remove "delete marker". See more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/undelete-objects.html